# Approximating $\textrm{AC}^{0}$ by sparse polynomials

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

Let $f$ be a Boolean function from $\{0,1\}^{n}$ to $\{0,1\}$.
We say that $f$ is randomly approximated with error probability $\epsilon$
by a family of polynomials $P$ if 
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in\{0,1\}^{n}\Pr_{p\in P}[p(x)=f(x)]\geq1-\epsilon
\end{equation}

It is known that if $f:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is computed
by an $s$ size bounded and $d$ depth bounded circuit of unbounded
fan-in, then $f$ can be randomly approximated with error probability
$\epsilon$ by a family of polynomials of degree $O(\log^{d}(\frac{s}{\epsilon})\cdot\log^{d}(s))$.

If $f$ can be computed by an $\textrm{AC}^{0}$ circuit then $s$ is polynomially
bounded by $n$ and $d$ is constant, hence $f$ can be randomly approximated
with constant error probability by a family of polynomials of degree
$\textrm{poly}(\log(n))$, which is low degree.

The number of monomials in these approximating polynomials may still be quasi-polynomial though.

What
if we want to approximate such $f\in\textrm{AC}^{0}$ by not low degree polynomials
but by family of polynomials which are **sparse**? Here, by sparse we would ideally
mean that number of monomial is something like $\textrm{poly}(n)$.

> Can we find a family
>   of sparse polynomials $P$ such that such $f$ is randomly approximated
>   with error probability $\epsilon$ by $P$ ?
>
> If not for $\textrm{AC}^{0}$,
>   what are other non trivial class of functions which can be approximated
>   by families of sparse polynomials.

Comment: something's wrong with your first equation. Are you sure you meant to write $Pr_{p \in P}$? Are you sure you meant to require p(x)=f(x)? (Hint: it's pretty hard for a polynomial over $\{0,1\}^n$ to be equal to $0$ or $1$.) Please make sure that your definition of "being approximated by a family of polynomials" makes sense and, if it is not a standard definition, try to explain how it differs from standard definitions: otherwise I suspect no one will understand the particular notion of approximation you're interested in.

Comment: Yes, such sparse polynomials would resolve many open problems... :)

Comment: @mobiusdumpling: The definition is actually standard. It originates in work of Toda & Ogiwara, Tarui, and Beigel, Reingold  & Spielman.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Ah, I see. So this is in some approximation-theory sense, and not in the Fourier sense. In the Fourier sense such approximation can probably be shown to not exist by considering the $L_1$ norm: the $L_1$ norm of $AC0$ can be $n^{\Omega(\log n)}$ IIRC, while the $L_1$ norm of a sparse polynomial must be $poly(n)$. So I'm guessing something in the approximation-theoretic sense of the definition allows the $L_1$ norm to explode. Probably the permission that in the $\epsilon$ fraction of the space where they're not equal, the polynomials can take any value.